# R Shiny - Using htmlOutput / uiOutput from UI.R in server.R as an input

Tags: html, r, shiny, render

In my shiny dashboard I am generating complex SQL that takes input from the user and generates the SQL code and executes it after the user has inputted their username / password.

I generate an htmlOutput in UI.R to show the code prior to code runs.

The code, when displayed as a textOutput contains line breaks *br()*, comments enclosed in *em()* and *shiny-html-output div* elements.

My objective is to be able to use the htmlOutput as an input in the sqlQuery function.

Parts of SERVER.R

```
qry_SQL <- reactive({tempfunc(1, "TD")})
# tempfunc creates my SQL using inputs present in UI.R

output$qry_out_text <- renderText(qry_SQL())
#Generates output in text format that contains <br/>, <em> and <div id="key1A_main_TD_1" class="shiny-html-output"> elements

output$qry_out_text2 <- renderUI(qry_SQL())
# Generates html output that I would ideally like to pass to sqlQuery

output$qry_out <- renderDataTable({
    input$Execute
    validate( 
      need(input$Username!=""&&input$Password!="","Please input Username and Password for TERADATA"),
      need(input$Execute>0,"Click Execute")
    ) 

    ch <- odbcConnect(dsn="CustomDSN",uid=input$Username, pwd = input$Password)

    import <<- sqlQuery(ch, PASS_HTML_OUTPUT_HERE, errors = FALSE    )    
    odbcClose(ch)   
    head(import, n =100)
  })
```

Ideally I need help on what to input in the **PASS_HTML_OUTPUT_HERE** block above.

qry_SQL() when outputted using textOutput yields the following:

```
SELECT c1.COL1, c1.COL2
FROM TABLE as c1  
WHERE cast(c1.DateNow as date) between '2015-09-19' and '2015-10-16'
and <div id="key1A_main_TD_1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
<div id="key2A_main_TD_1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
<div id="key3A_main_TD_1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
<div id="key4A_main_TD_1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
<div id="key5A_main_TD_1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
```

In this case key1A_main_TD_1 yields "( AND c1.Details like '%unhappy%') "
The other div tags do not yield anything as nothing has been inputted by the user.

qry_SQL() when outputted using htmlOutput yields the following:

```
SELECT c1.COL1, c2.COL2
FROM TABLE1 as c1 
WHERE cast(c1.DateNow as date) between '2015-09-19' and '2015-10-16'
and
(c1.Details like '%unhappy%')
```

My problem is that I would like to pass qry_SQL() as HTML, with the div tags resolved.

Cheers,
Anand

Comment: Could you post a example of the HTML? do you want to save the HTML or extract a SQL query from the HTML?

Comment: From the coments on your code, it looks like you'd want to use `qry_SQL()`. But the `temoofunc` looks like it has got no `input` from the user... It's hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to include the values of qry_SQL() as textOutput and htmlOutput.  I basically wish to resolve div tags when passing qry_SQL() to the sqlQuery() function